# Transformar múltiplos arquivos css em um único com PostCSS

Tags: css, gulpjs

Uso PostCSS para gerar um framework css, consigo usá-lo numa boa, meu único problema é a saída. Se eu tenho 8 arquivos CSS o PostCSS me gera e trata os 8, em novos 8 arquivos, mas o ideal para mim seria uni-los em um único arquivo.

Alguém sabe se seria possível fazer isso com PostCSS ou de outra forma dinâmica?

A solução não precisa ser necessariamente com gulpjs.

Desde agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com o "gulp-concat" que concatena arquivos.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat